# Are there resources that classify the common words according to their underlying concepts?

Tags: cognitive-linguistics, resource-request

Are there available resources that classify the common words (used in daily life for communications) in the form of a hierarchy according to their underlying concepts (possibly also w.r.p.t. synonyms/antonyms), analogous to classification of the special words used in many scientific fields, e.g. in medicine where the diverse illnesses are classified into a hierarchy (that is reflected at a higher level in the courses taught in the universites and in the structures of the hospitals)?

Comment: Do you mean something like the semantic fields used by a thesaurus, e.g., Roget's?

Comment: I have never used Roget. But the theasurus I possess apparently couldn't help me much to establish a hierarchy of the genre I depicted.

Comment: I just got a hint to UBY https://www.ukp.tu-darmstadt.de/data/lexical-resources/uby/ which seems to be a highly sophisticated software that is relevant for my purposes. If someone has experiences with it, I should appreciate to know of them.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear to me how fine-grained the resource should be, but for a starter there is the [Princeton Wordnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet).

For specialised domains several [ontologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29) exsts (some free, some to be licenced).

Comment: I clicked on "ongologies" but got error message "server not found". I prefer to have somewhat more fine-grained recources than Wordnet.

Comment: @Mok-Kong Shen: Thank for the notification, I have fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

[Babelnet](http://babelnet.org/about) is has [word senses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_sense) for words in many languages.

For example, for [[get]](http://babelnet.org/search?word=get&lang=EN):

- *GET* the HTTP method
- *get* n - divorce document
- *get* n - male's offspring
- *get* v - meaning *to understand*
- *get* v - meaning *to obtain*
  ...

It includes data from Wiktionary, Princeton WordNet et altri.

Comment: Word sense is not what I primarily need but the position of a word in the hierarchy of concepts (e.g. what is "nut" in relation to "food" and what are the different kinds of nuts).